# Spring: disabling validation also disables autowiring?

Tags: spring, validation

As I had to learn the typical Spring configuration files headers, e.g.:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd"
    default-autowire="byName">
    ...
```

do indeed cause Spring to reach out and fetch the referenced .xsd files from the Internet for validation of the config file(s). If it can not find or download those schemas, it fails.

Since the code that I am developing will later run on servers that won't have access to the internet I need to prevent this! To do so, I wanted to simply disable validation (which is no issue, since the config files are thoroughly tested before the code ever gets operational).

So I came up with the following class derived from ClassPathXmlApplicationContext which overrides a single method in order to disable config-file validation:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appSpringContext = 
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] { 
        "config/context_basicfw.xml",
        "config/context_sbase.xml",
        "config/openApi.xml",
    }) {
    @Override
    protected void initBeanDefinitionReader(XmlBeanDefinitionReader beanDefinitionReader) {
        super.initBeanDefinitionReader(beanDefinitionReader);
        beanDefinitionReader.setValidationMode(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.VALIDATION_NONE);
        beanDefinitionReader.setNamespaceAware(true);
    }
};
```

But to my dismay this not only disables validation but - for some strange reason - also the auto-wiring of beans! I.e. if I comment away the two added lines (following the super...-call) in the overriding method initBeanDefinitionReader() then my code runs fine. If I enable those two lines, then the initialization runs fine without downloading any schemas but my code later throws NullPointerExceptions because of several beans which are supposed to be assigned via auto-wiring still being null.

How can I disable Spring's config file validation while maintaining full Spring functionality, specifically the auto-wiring?

Note: I know that I could change my config files to point to local copies of the schemas, but this would work only for config files that I have control of. However, we are using a couple of .jars that contain their own config files with headers like the above and - if anyhow possible - I don't want to touch those but use them as is, i.e. without having to unpack them, modifying the spring config files and re-packaging them.

Any idea or suggestion anyone, how to tell Spring to skip validation, but still do auto-wiring? 
BTW: I am forced to still use Spring v2.0, no higher version!

Comment: Don't... Your efforts are useless, Spring ships with its own xsd which are used from inside the jar. SO what you are doing or trying is basically pointless.

Comment: Now that is strange! You are absolutely right! Just to verify I removed my validation-suppression botch, disconnected the system from all networks and re-ran my code and it all started up fine! When I had tested that earlier I had run into Exceptions during Spring initialization due to timed-out connection attempts accessing those Spring .xsd URLs. I guess I must have had some classpath issues then that I apparently resolved in the mean time without even noticing that this also fixed these schema downloads. It's now all working as I had originally expected! Thanks a lot!